# Make Equal-Width SwiftUI Views in List Rows

Tags: swiftui

I have a `List` that displays days in the current month. Each row in the `List` contains the abbreviated day, a `Divider`, and the day number within a `VStack`. The `VStack` is then embedded in an `HStack` so that I can have more text to the right of the day and number.

```swift
struct DayListItem : View {

    // MARK: - Properties

    let date: Date

    private let weekdayFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEE"
        return formatter
    }()

    private let dayNumberFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d"
        return formatter
    }()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(weekdayFormatter.string(from: date))
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                Text(dayNumberFormatter.string(from: date))
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }

}
```

Instances of `DayListItem` are used in `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private let dataProvider = CalendricalDataProvider()

    private var navigationBarTitle: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM YYY"
        return formatter.string(from: Date())
    } 

    private var currentMonth: Month {
        dataProvider.currentMonth
    }

    private var months: [Month] {
        return dataProvider.monthsInRelativeYear
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(currentMonth.days.identified(by: \.self)) { date in
                DayListItem(date: date)
            }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(navigationBarTitle))
                .listStyle(.grouped)
        }
    }

}
```

The result of the code is below:

[image: Screenshot of app running in Xcode Simulator]

It may not be obvious, but the dividers are not lined up because the width of the text can vary from row to row. What I would like to achieve is to have the views that contains the day information be the same width so that they are visually aligned.

I have tried using a `GeometryReader` and the `frame()` modifiers to set the minimum width, ideal width, and maximum width, but I need to ensure that the text can shrink and grow with Dynamic Type settings; I chose not to use a width that is a percentage of the parent because I was uncertain how to be sure that localized text would always fit within the allowed width.

How can I modify my views so that each view in the row is the same width, regardless of the width of text?

Regarding Dynamic Type, I will create a different layout to be used when that setting is changed.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I got this to work using `GeometryReader` and `Preferences`.

First, in `ContentView`, add this property:

```swift
@State var maxLabelWidth: CGFloat = .zero
```

Then, in `DayListItem`, add this property:

```swift
@Binding var maxLabelWidth: CGFloat
```

Next, in `ContentView`, pass `self.$maxLabelWidth` to each instance of `DayListItem`:

```swift
List(currentMonth.days.identified(by: \.self)) { date in
    DayListItem(date: date, maxLabelWidth: self.$maxLabelWidth)
}
```

Now, create a struct called `MaxWidthPreferenceKey`:

```swift
struct MaxWidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = .zero
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        let nextValue = nextValue()
        
        guard nextValue > value else { return }
        
        value = nextValue
    }
}
```

This conforms to the `PreferenceKey` protocol, allowing you to use this struct as a key when communicating preferences between your views.

Next, create a `View` called `DayListItemGeometry` - this will be used to determine the width of the `VStack` in `DayListItem`:

```swift
struct DayListItemGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear
                .preference(key: MaxWidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
        }
        .scaledToFill()
    }
}
```

Then, in `DayListItem`, change your code to this:

```swift
HStack {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text(weekdayFormatter.string(from: date))
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        Text(dayNumberFormatter.string(from: date))
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
    .background(DayListItemGeometry())
    .onPreferenceChange(MaxWidthPreferenceKey.self) {
        self.maxLabelWidth = $0
    }
    .frame(width: self.maxLabelWidth)

    Divider()
}
```

What I've done is I've created a `GeometryReader` and applied it to the background of the `VStack`. The geometry tells me the dimensions of the `VStack` which sizes itself according to the size of the text. `MaxWidthPreferenceKey` gets updated whenever the geometry changes, and after the `reduce` function inside `MaxWidthPreferenceKey` calculates the maximum width, I read the preference change and update `self.maxLabelWidth`. I then set the frame of the `VStack` to be `.frame(width: self.maxLabelWidth)`, and since `maxLabelWidth` is binding, every `DayListItem` is updated when a new `maxLabelWidth` is calculated. Keep in mind that the order matters here. Placing the `.frame` modifier before `.background` and `.onPreferenceChange` will not work.

[image: Canvas Screenshot]

Comment: That is the exact behavior that I was looking for! Do you recall where you learned about the `PreferenceKey` protocol? I looked at the documentation, but it's quite lacking.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the documentation for SwiftUI is pretty much non-existent. I learned about `PreferenceKey` from this [article](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/). They only have a couple articles up so far, but the ones they do have up have already helped me a lot, so I would keep an eye out for when they post more.

Comment: @graycampbell `scaledToFill` causes my content to squash the rest of the row's content. If I remove it, then the modified content is crazy thin. How do I measure the original width of the content that's to be modified?

Comment: This has gotten 28 upvotes, so it must have worked at some point. I am encountering a bug for which a radar has been filed, but no solution offered.  "Bound preference WidthPreferenceKey tried to update multiple times per frame."  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: @IanWarburton I’m not sure what the problem would be. I haven’t looked at this in a long time. I’ll try to take a look when I have time.

Comment: @Mozahler Yeah, that’s an error I’ve come across before. I don’t remember it being a problem with this when I wrote the answer. I’ll try to take a look at this when I have time.

Comment: @Mozahler I've updated my answer. It should fix issues with max width calculations. I wasn't getting the same error you were though, so I'm not sure if it will fix that. Let me know if the problem is still there after trying my updated answer.

Comment: @graycampbell - thanks for looking into this! I'm still getting "tried to update multiple times per frame" - I'm using a ForEach rather than List. I'll play with this a bit and see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I had the list embedded inside a scroll view. I removed it and the error went away. thanks again!

Comment: Is it suitable for calculate self sizing view by maxHeight ?

Comment: Great answer. This didn't work for me (the `PreferenceKey`'s `reduce()` method wasn't being called) until I removed the `.onPreferenceChange` block from `DayListItem` and attached it instead to the enclosing `List` (i.e. I moved `onPreferenceChange` up the view hierarchy to an ancestor view that contained all the views that modify the `MaxWidthPreferenceKey`).

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to achieve something similar. My text in one of the label in a row was varying from 2 characters to 20 characters. It messes up the horizontal alignment. I was looking to make this column in row as fixed width. And here is a very simple solution I applied to achieve that and it worked for me. Hope it can benefit someone else too.

```
var body: some View { // view for each row in list
        VStack(){
            HStack {
                  Text(wire.labelValueDate)
                        .
                        .
                        .foregroundColor(wire.labelColor)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                        .frame(width: 110.0, alignment: .trailing)
                    }
                  }
}
```