# Get View Size inside Grouped List in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-environment

I'm currently using a `List` with a `GroupedListStyle()`, and with a `.regular horizontalSizeClass` (e.g an iPad in landscape mode), this style of List automatically creates some padding to each section, like this:

```swift
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Text("One")
                Text("Two")
                Text("Three")
            }
        }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

[image: Sample Grouped List Style]

This is great, I want this. But since I need to display some elements inside the rows with a **fixed width**, I need to know the actual width of the row inside the List.

I've tried wrapping the List with a GeometryReader, but the width doesn't match the row's width because of the padding around the entire `Section`.

```swift
struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
             List {
                Section {
                    Text("One")  // <-- geometry.size.width != Text.width
                    Text("Two")
                    Text("Three")
                }
             }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

So I've tried using the PreferenceKey method [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56997725/make-equal-width-swiftui-views-in-list-rows) by putting a `GeometryReader` in the `listRowBackground` modifier of the row, but **the value is never updated**.

Is there a working way to get the size of the parent, without using a  `GeometryReader` around the parent (as it is finnicky on a List, and needs to be specified Height and Width to work properly)?

Comment: What exactly do you need to know the height of? Section or row element?

Comment: Try the `defaultMinListRowHeight` Environment value like this: `@Environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight) var height`

Comment: So do you want to read row's width or text's width? Because those are different widths. Row's width is equal for all rows in table. Text's width depend on content, of course.

Comment: I need to read the row's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to resort to a `UITableView` with style `.insetGrouped`, implemented with a `Representable` and used the property `layoutMargins` that gives exactly the size of the horizontal margins in this size class.